# Getting around an error with dashboard running?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm working on a dashboard right now that I cannot run because of an error I'm getting that shows up like this.:

```
Error in tagAssert(icon, type = "i") : 
  Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
```

I'll paste my code below, but I'm not sure what my error is. All my packages, RStudio and R are up to date, so it's not that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# Source Scripts ----
source("EDU 291 Libraries.R", local = TRUE)
source("EDU 291 Data.R", local = TRUE)
source("EDU 291 uiPanels.R", local = TRUE)
source("EDU 291 Utils.R", local = TRUE)
#sample change
# UI ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "COVID Cases Dashboard" )
  , dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(tabName = "dashboard", text = "Dashboard", icon = icon("map"))
      , menuItem(tabName = "graphs", text = "Graphs", icon = icon("graph"))
      , menuItem(tabName = "sources", text = "Sources", icon =("book"))
    )
  )
  , dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 12, status = "primary", title = "Draft FOR NOW"
          , column(width = 4
                   , tabItems(
                     dashboard
                   )
          )
          , column(width = 8
                   , leafletOutput("map")
          )
          )
      )
    )
  )

# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # test for push
  
  # Filters/Sliders

  output$instPicker <- renderUI({
    ls_institution <- covid_data %>%
      select(institution) %>%
      filter(institution != "") %>%
      distinct()%>%
      pull()
    ls_institution <- sort(ls_institution)
    ls_institution <-  prepend(ls_institution, "Nothing Selected", before = 1)
    pickerInput(inputId = 'instPicker'
                , label = "Peer Institutions"
                , choices = ls_institution
                , selected = ls_institution[1]
                , options = pickerOptions(liveSearch = T, liveSearchStyle = 'startsWith')
    )
  })
  
  output$enrollmentSlider <- renderUI({
    sizeStart <- min(covid_data$enrollment)
    sizeEnd <- max(covid_data$enrollment)
    sliderInput(inputId = "enrollmentSize"
                , label = "Undergraduate Enrollment"
                , min = sizeStart
                , max = sizeEnd
                , value = c(sizeStart, sizeEnd)
                , ticks = F)
  })
  
  output$reportMethodFilter <- renderUI({
    ls_reportMethod <- c("bad"
                         , "coming soon (e.g. the university has announced that a dashboard will exist)"
                         , "online dashboard"
                         , "other"
                         , "reporting cumulative cases only"
                         , "via a campus newsletter")
    pickerInput(inputId = "reportMethod", label = "Report Method", choices = ls_reportMethod,
                multiple = T, selected = ls_reportMethod)
    
  })
  
  output$updateFrequencyFilter <- renderUI({
    ls_updateFrequency <- c("daily"
                         , "monthly"
                         , "unsure"
                         , "other"
                         , "weekdays only"
                         , "weekly")
    pickerInput(inputId = "updateFrequency", label = "Update Frequency", choices = ls_updateFrequency,
                multiple = T, selected = ls_updateFrequency)
    
  })
  
  #reactive data
  fallMapData <- reactive({
    req(input$instPicker)
    df <- covid_data
   
     #institution picker
    if(input$instPicker != "Nothing Selected"){
      df <- df %>% filter(institution %in% input$instPicker)
    }
    
    df %>%
      filter(
        !is.na(mapGroup)
        , updateFrequency %in% input$updateFrequency
        , reportMethod %in% input$reportMethod
        , enrollment >= input$enrollmentSize[1] & enrollment <= input$enrollmentSize[2]
      )
  })
  
# End of server
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I need to add the code from my other pages let me know but I don't think that's the issue right now.

Comment: This line looks janky... `menuItem(tabName = "sources", text = "Sources", icon =("book"))`

Comment: Maybe you wanted `icon =icon(“book”)`

Comment: So I fixed the 3rd menu item line, but now I get this error: ``` Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
``` Any advice for this?

Comment: Update, I've made some changes and now I'm here: Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
  [No stack trace available]. Dashboard opens but I see that error.